# Style teaching bubble with different background color than it's coachmark

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I am using a teaching bubble inside a coach mark, same as the example in here

[enter link description here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/coachmark)

How can I have the teaching bubble in white instead of blue?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the `styles` prop to the `TeachingBubbleContent` that contain this object:

```
{
  closeButton: {
    color: 'red',
    selectors: {
      ':hover': {
        background: 'gainsboro',
        color: 'red'
      },
      ':active': {
        background: 'darkGray',
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  },
  content: {
    border: '1px solid black',
    background: 'white',
  },
  headline: {
    color: 'black'
  },
  subText: {
    color: 'black'
  }
}
```

Example here in this codepen: https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/xoEPzg.

The only thing thing you can't do easily is to change the `Coachmark`'s drop color in a way that is still visible. You can try by passing `color` prop to it and specify `white`, but because there is no border or shadow around the drop all you'll see is the beacon animation. And if you try give it a border it won't look nice (see codepen) because of how the drop is constructed. Also, there is currently a bug in passing the `beaconColorOne` and `beaconColorTwo` props to change the beacon color that I am fixing right now :)

Hope that helps!